# Uncaught TypeError: getImage.crop is not a function

Tags: javascript, filereader, react-konva, konva

The code I get this error is:

```js
const crop = imageSrc.crop({
  x: value.x / ratio_w,
  y: value.y / ratio_h,
  width: value.width / ratio_w,
  height: value.height / ratio_h,
});
```

I got this error when I was trying to get a subimage with the x,y, width and height coordinates of the image area to get. In there I declare

```js
const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState(null)
```

and I update the value of imageSrc here:

```js
const handleImageChange = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setImageSrc(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};
```

According to Konva's documentation, there are instructions:

```js
// get crop
var crop = image.crop();
```

I asked in repo of konva but no one respond my question.

Comment: `readAsDataURL()` resolves with a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result#value. It's not clear at all why you think that would be an [Image](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Image.html)

Comment: ^^^ let alone a *konva* image

Comment: @JaromandaX check the link 

Comment: @Phil ... yeah, I get that, my point was why would OP think `FileReader` would return a new Konva image - regardless of which FileReader method they used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [FileReader: readDataAsURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)...

> the result attribute contains the data as a data: URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.

This is a string, not a [Konva.Image](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Image.html).

You will need to load the result using something like [Konva.Image.fromURL()](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Image.html#.Image.fromURL__anchor) before you can use methods like `crop()`

```js
reader.onloadend = () => {
  Konva.Image.fromURL(reader.result, setImageSrc, console.error);
};
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I did that and it worked perfectly, and I tried the consolog crop and it looked like this: `Image {_id: 5, eventListeners: {…}, attrs: {…}, index: 0, _allEventListeners: null, …}`
I would appreciate it if you could tell me more, how do I display const crop as an image?

Comment: @nothing presumably you'd add the image to a Konva stage and draw it. I've never used Konva, I'm just looking at the documentation. I suggest you do the same. There's an example here ~ https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Image.html

Comment: There's React specific examples here ~ https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html